# Gitorious Rots Ruby on Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have recently updated my gitorious instance and I’m getting an error now.

Error message: 
https://github.com/roman/rots.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError) 
Exception class: 
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError 
Application root: 
/var/www/gitorious

Does anyone have ideia how could i fix it? I have tried run bundle pack and bundle install but it didnt solve

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved downgrading it, checking out an older gitorious version and running bundle install and bundle pack but there's gitorious recommendation for upgrading in the wiki.

Answer (score 5):

I got this from another thread but it seemed to work for me.

bundle pack

bundle install --path vendor/cache

That last command seemed to really do a git clone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the clone URL (https://github.com/roman/rots.git) specified in the Gemfile is not anonymously clonable when you `bundle install` dependencies, which is why myself (and other on other forums) are getting an HTTP 403 is similar contexts. Try editing the Gemfile and using the git protocol version of the URL instead:

```
git://github.com/roman/rots.git
```

As soon as I made this change I could `bundle install` to get the dependency cloned as expected, and move on to the next issue. :)